# CMake: Set ggc-min-expand and -heapsize with target_compile_options

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, cmake, resources

Minimal working example at the bottom.

Let's suppose I want to modify GCC garbage collection for a particular CMake target, call it foo. My instinct would be to try, for example:

```
target_compile_options(foo <PRIVATE|INTERFACE|PUBLIC> --param ggc-min-heapsize=32768)
```

This works fine. But if I try:

```
target_compile_options(foo <PRIVATE|INTERFACE|PUBLIC> --param ggc-min-expand=1 --param ggc-min-heapsize=32768)
```

or

```
target_compile_options(foo <PRIVATE|INTERFACE|PUBLIC> --param ggc-min-expand=1)
target_compile_options(foo <PRIVATE|INTERFACE|PUBLIC> --param ggc-min-heapsize=32768)
```

I get in response:

```
ggc-min-heapsize=32768: No such file or directory
```

Adding quotes around the arguments or around each argument doesn't help. I've tried this on CMake 3.5.1 and 3.11, GCC 4.8 and GCC 7, no changes.

Oddly, the old-style

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --param ggc-min-expand=1 --param ggc-min-heapsize=32768)
```

Seems to work just fine. Am I missing something about modern usage of target_compile_options?

## Minimal Working Example

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project(test)

add_executable(test main.cpp) 
target_compile_options(test PRIVATE --param ggc-min-expand=1)
// Uncommenting the below causes compilation to fail
// target_compile_options(test PRIVATE --param ggc-min-heapsize=32768)
```

### main.cpp

```
int main() {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that CMake de-duplicates flags passed to `target_compile_options`, so it ends up passing "--param gcc-min-expand=1 gcc-min-heapsize=32768" to gcc.  This is obviously wrong.  There's [an issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15826) with people complaining about it.

To get around this, some new functionality was [recently added](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/1841).  You can wrap the options in quotes and prepend `SHELL:`.  The arguments will be treated as a single unit for de-duplication purposes, but will be passed to gcc as multiple arguments (as if split by your shell).  This change was released in CMake 3.12, so the version from your distro's package manager probably doesn't have it yet.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project(example)

add_executable(example main.cpp) 
target_compile_options(example PRIVATE "SHELL:--param ggc-min-expand=1")
target_compile_options(example PRIVATE "SHELL:--param ggc-min-heapsize=32768")
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and coherent explanation. This probably means it's time to bite the bullet and build the most recent CMake from source.